# Override Bundle classloader in OSGi?

Tags: java, osgi, classloader

Is this possible somehow?

I mean for *my own* bundle?

Thank you
Misha

p.s. More specifically, I am interesting in having a class *within* my bundle (well, within a fragment) return *my custom classloader* from a call to

MyClass.class.getClassLoader()

rather than the bundle's???

Thank you very much

Yours
Misha

p.s. Some helpful links I've found that don't seem to answer this question :(

http://shylendrabhat.com/blog/2009/11/21/class-loader-architecture-comparison-java-j2ee-and-osgi/

http://codescale.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/basics-about-osgi-classloading/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Equinox as your OSGi implementation, I think you can have a look the [classloader hook](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Adaptor_Hooks#Class_Loading_Hook).

You can check out the code of [Equinox Transforms](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms) to see how to contribute your hook.